# cancelling C# async function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

**I have the following program:**

```
class myClass
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts;

    public string someMethod(){
        someMethodWhichIsAsync("10")
    }

    private async Task<string> someMethodWhichIsAsync(string data)
    {
        if(cts != null)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }

        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        string myString = await Task.Run(() => someLoop(data,cts.Token) );

        return "success";
    }

    private string someLoop(string data, CancellationToken token)
    {

            while (True)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested == true)
                {
                    return "Canceled";
                }

                //Do some work in a continuous loop

            }

            return "successful end";

    }
}
```

I have placed CancellationTokenSource cts; in the class global scope so that it is available every time any function runs.

However cts.Cancel(); only works if I include it inside the function which runs.

```
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested == true)
        {
            return "Canceled";
        }
```

**Why is this?** None of the example code I found requires this.

Comment: Async cancellation is cooperative: cancelling the token source is only a signal, it will not stop anything. You need to handle cancellation. Either by throwing an exception or abandoning gracefully whatever you do...

Comment: The sample code might use another technique, e.g. use ThrowIfCancellationRequested. It would then exit via the catch block.

Comment: would ThrowIfCancellationRequested work even if the thread has got past the point where ThrowIfCancellationRequested runs before the cancelation request occurs

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I see from documentation, CancellationTokenSource.Cancel is only sending a SIGNAL that the process should be cancelled. Then, with the Token of the Source, you check whether the Cancellation had been requested (which holds True only if you called the Cancel method before). So, this line is necessary to actually Cancel the operation.

Comment: In that case how can you cancel a function which takes a long time to run (such as a HTTP call)

In my code the cancelation works because there is a loop
but what would you do in non looping cases

Comment: @megaman - You can't. The only (semi-)safe way to cancel code that you do not have control over is to spin up a completely new os-level process and run the code there - you can kill the process if you need to.

Comment: @megaman It depends. In the case of networking functions you could just cancel the request or close the connection when the cancellation is sent – that’s what the CancellationToken's Register method is for.

Comment: can things like cancel and sleep be done if you use Thread() instead of Task()